# TCL script cannot keep the 64bit pointer returned from C-API

Tags: tcl, swig, 32bit-64bit

I have an old TCL script which runs well on 32-bit machine, but got 'Segmentation fault' on 64-bit machine.The script is like this:

```
...
set msgHeader [ headerGet ]
setAnswerMessageHeader $cmd 0x00 $msgHeader
...
```

Here headerGet and setAnswerMessageHeader are C-APIs which are like this:

```
static MsgHeader_t currHeader;

MsgHeader_t *
headerGet(void)
{
    printf("***********     headerGet: %p\n", &currHeader);
    return &currHeader;
}

int
setAnswerMessageHeader(Msg_t * cmd, W8 cmdFlags, MsgHeader_t * hdr)
{
    printf("***********     setAnswerMessageHeader, cmd=%p, cmdFlags=%d, hdr=%p\n", cmd, cmdFlags, hdr);

    ...

    return RETURN_OK;
}
```

Here is my debug output on 64-bit machine:

```
***********     headerGet: 0x7f86ab50edb0
***********     setAnswerMessageHeader, cmd=0x337c950, cmdFlags=0, hdr=0xffffffffab50edb0
```

So, the problem is: headerGet returns address 0x7f86**ab50edb0** to msgHeader variant, but when TCL passes it to setAnswerMessageHeader, the address is wrong totally. Looks like only the last-four bytes (0x**ab50edb0**) of the addess are kept. **The first two (0x7f86) are lost**.

BTW: my tcl version is 8.5

I am unfamliar with TCL/TK. Is there anyone knowing why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: What are you using to make the binding layer between your C++ code and your Tcl code? I ask because that's where the bug is…

Comment: It's SWIG. I checked in my env and found it's 32-bit. So maybe it's the cause. I will update it and run again. Thanks for your 'ask' which actually gives me a direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the build of SWIG that you're using, in that it is treating the pointer as a 32-bit value (which throws away those significant bits). You need SWIG to understand that it must generate 64-bit aware code so that pointers get mapped correctly.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Any idea how to make SWIG to generate 64-bit aware codes?